# Z-Test application

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> The life of a cell can be measured by $X\sim Exp(0.1)$. After a procedure "S" the life of the cell is given by $X\sim Exp(\lambda_1).$ From a sample of $200$ we know $\sum_{i=1}^{200} x_i=1182.5$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{200} x_i^2=13239.14$ with $c=95\%$. Determine if the cell lives longer.

I can calculate the mean and deviation

$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{200}\sum_{i=1}^{200}x_i=1182,25/200=5,91.$

$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{200}\sum_{i=1}^{200}(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2)}\\ = \sqrt{\frac{1}{200}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{200}x_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^{200}x_i\bar{x}+\sum_{i=1}^{200}\bar{x}^2\right)}\\= \sqrt{\frac{1}{200}\left(13239,14-2(5,91)\sum_{i=1}^{200}x_i+\sum_{i=1}^{200}(5,91)^2\right)} \\
 =\sqrt{\frac{1}{200}\left(13239,14-2(5,91)(1182,25)+(200)(5,91)^2\right)}\\
=5.59. $

Because both before and after are exponential distribution I consider the hypothesis may be

$ 
 \begin{cases}
 H_0: & \lambda_1\leq 0.1 \\
 H_1: & \lambda_1 > 0.1
 \end{cases}
$

Using z-test

$z=\displaystyle \frac{\bar{x}-0.1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}= \frac{5.91-0.1}{(5.59)\sqrt{200}}=0.074$

Because $c=95\%$ then $\alpha= 0.05$ and according to the $z-table$ the z-score is 1.645. The result doesn't fall into the rejection region then according to the test the cell do not lives longer.

Is it correct? I am particularly unsure about the hypothesis I've chosen.

Comment: To be honest, I would think that a user of your rep would use display-style MathJax by now. Also, `\exp` $\exp$ has its own command.

Comment: Imprecisely phrased question. Hoping for clarifications: You use both $\mu$ and $\lambda.$ When you say $X_i \sim \mathsf{Exp}(0.1),$ do you intend the parameterization in which $E(X_i) = \mu = 0.1,$ where $\mu$ is the expected lifetime? Or do you mean $E(X_i) = 1/\lambda,$ where $\lambda$ is the death rate. // Also the distribution of the mean of 200 exponential observations has exactly a gamma distribution and is only approximately normal. // Is the 'treatment' intended to extend cell life? Or (perhaps for cancer cells) shorten it?

Comment: @BruceET The exponential distribution stands for the lifetime. The use of $\lambda$ was to test if the lifetime was extended. There was a subscript missing, I am testing $\lambda_1$ because the expected lifetime is $Exp (\lambda_1)$ against $Exp (\lambda)=Exp(0,1)$ before the treatment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not available today, but will look later to see if you have an answer.// For variance: let $T=\sum_i X_i$ so that $\bar X = T/n$. Also let $Q = \sum_i X_i^2.$ Then samp var $S^2 = [Q -n\bar X^2]/(n-1).$ Not saying your computation is wrong, but this is simpler and you might use it to check.

Comment: Doing the arithmetic correctly, Z≈14.6, which gives an entirely different result. (In the denom, divide by $\sqrt{200}.)$ The question remains whether μ=λ and hence whether this is a properly formed z-value. An increase from pop mean .1 to sample mean 5.59 seems quite spectacular, if that is really what you are testing? Please make appropriate changes to your Question. For exponential data the pop mean and pop SD should be the same: 5.91 and 5.59 are encouragingly similar sample values.

Comment: @BruceET  It is the first time I hear "pop mean". I wanted to determine if the hypothesis "the treatment did not work" was more likely that "the treatment worked". Because the life of the non-treated cell is $Exp(\lambda)$ with $\lambda=0.1$ and the life of the treated cell is $Exp(\lambda_1)$ for unknown $\lambda_1$, but it is known that the latter cell verifies the summations, I decided to test $\lambda_1$ against $\lambda=0.1$. Maybe I had to test something different for my purposes?

Comment: @BruceET I checked the arithmetic again. I don't get the value $z\sim 14.6$